# What does $W_1(\mu_n,\mu)\to 0$ mean?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I try to understand the following theorem of the Wasserstein distance of two Borel probability measures:
[image]

Here $\mu\in W_p(X)$ means $\int_X \|x\|^p d\mu(x)<\infty$.

My question is that what does $W_1(\mu_n,\mu)\to 0$ mean? Which is mode of this convergence?

For $p=1$, $W_1(\mu_n,\mu)=\inf\int |x-y|d\pi(x,y)$. How to understand the coupling of $\mu_n$ and $\mu$ here?

Comment: Each value is a number so we just have the usual convergence of a sequence. Pointwise, measure, uniform etc. would apply if each term depended on $x,$ but each term is a real number.

Comment: @Displayname Can you explain in details? I do not understand how to take $n\to\infty$ inside Wasserstein distance.

Comment: Each $W_1(\mu_n, \mu)$ is a number, you have a sequence of numbers.

Comment: @Displayname So you mean $W_1(\mu_n, \mu)$ is a sequence $a_n$. Then the limit is just the limit of sequence? So which mode of limit in this theorem?

Comment: There's only one mode of convergence for a sequence of real numbers. Uniform, pointwise, and all the other types are the same for it.